# PCB trace caps (a.k.a. finger / interdigital caps) formula

Tags: capacitor, pcb, trace

I am trying to calculate a two-fingered, both on the same layer, capacitor. I have run into a few papers on it but they are taking a ground plane on the other side of the PCB into consideration and they seem to be showing a meandered capacitor like this one

[image]

which is not exactly what I was looking for. I am after a simpler design:
[image]

I know that the capacitance formula is [image]
where A = t * L; 
t being the thickness of the copper pour and L being the length on which the two traces juxtapose, thus forming the plates of our capacitor.
Should I apply it as such (no ground plane beneath) ? Am I also right to be using these values ?

- epsilon_r = 1 for air
- t = 35 microns for 1 oz copper

Comment: \$\epsilon_R\$ is 1 for air, but some of the field will be in the PCB material rather than in air.

Comment: @ThePhoton I was afraid taht would be the case :S

Comment: I found one formula for calculating Er in a coplanar waveguide. You could try using that. The formula is kind of involved. You can find it in this PDF: https://www.jlab.org/accel/eecad/pdf/050rfdesign.pdf. Make sure you use the formula for the ungrounded coplanar waveguide.

Comment: Are there any other layers? Do they have copper on them anywhere near where the traces overlap? If you have any copper plane or fill on another layer near the two traces, that will greatly increase the capacitance.

Comment: Also don't forget about solder-mask. Either remove it or account for its Er of 3 to 5 (depending on the material, there's also outliers of 2 and 7 for speciality purposes)

Comment: @mkeith Good find! However I am not sure of what the `K` and `K'` functions are. They don't appear to be described in the document. Any hints ?

Comment: Yeah, I am not following the terminology. But from a later example, it appears that the effective Er is around 2.44 or 2.45. Maybe just try working out your problem using that, and see how it goes?